# bash execute command inside every subfolder, using the subfolder's name as part of the command, for tens of thousands of items

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I really suck at this stuff.  I'm trying to organize our 70k+ photo collection.

I want to use exiftool to geotag each file.  I've painstakenly moved all the photos into about 100 subfolders, each of those is named by its longitude, latitude.

for example:

/pictures/-13.84101666169794, -76.25097514822582/*

(where * is an unknown number of jpg and nothing else)

Let's say the command I want to run is as follows:

```
exiftool -m -overwrite_original -GPSLatitudeRef=S -GPSLongitudeRef=W -GPSLatitude=-13.84101666169794 -GPSLongitude=-76.25097514822582 .
```

I want to iterate over every coordinate-named folder, extract the coordinates from the folder name and apply the command to each folder, using those coordinates.

If the first coordinate is a negative, then GPSLatitudeRef has to be S.  If positive, it changes to N.  Similar for E/W for longitude.

This would take me forever to figure out, but I'm hoping it is trivial for someone willing to help :)  I don't want to screw it up.  I have backups, of course, but just copying this amount of files to try again takes over half an hour!

Note: for my case, there are no further nested subfolders, so recursing further down is not necessary. If it matters, the number of digits in the coordinate names to the right of the decimals are consistent but there could be 1, 2 or 3 digits to the left (plus, of course, the minus-sign or not)

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused, because there was an answer here from someone, but now it is gone?  It was quite helpful.  There was just a small flaw related to the directory names starting with a hypen.  This worked for me:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cd ./pictures

 for dir in *; do
     lat=${dir%,*}
     long=${dir#*, }

     case $lat in
     -*) ns=S ;;
      *) ns=N
     esac

     case $long in
     -*) ew=W ;;
      *) ew=E
     esac
     exiftool -F -m -overwrite_original -GPSLatitudeRef=$ns -GPSLongitudeRef=$ew -GPSLatitude=$lat -GPSLongitude=$long -- "$dir"/
  done
```